# In Django, what does it mean to generate an action in a separate signal?

Tags: django, notifications, signals

In Django, what does it mean to generate an action in a separate signal?

For example, is this documentation here: https://github.com/brantyoung/django-notifications

It states: Generating notifications is probably best done in a separate signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation you mentioned, there are two signals used by the example. The first one is `notifications.notify` and the other one is `django.db.models.signals.post_save`.

In order to use the notification app, basically you only need the first signal. For example, anywhere in your code you can write:

```
notify.send(request.user, verb='reached level 10')
```

However, the writer suggest that you should emit the notify signal *after* (or when) you handle another signal. Hence the example below:

```
def my_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    #other routines here
    notify.send(instance, verb='was saved')

post_save.connect(my_handler, sender=MyModel)
```

That is, you send the notify signal as a part of the post_save signal handler.

Comment: Hey Pram, how can I for example create a notification where a user from my user model comments on a picture from another user? For example, 'Bob commented on Kyle's photo' in a activity feed style?

Comment: I haven't use the app. However from the doc, I think you can use this statement:
notify.send(request.user, verb='created comment', target=photo)

In your case, the actor is Bob, the verb is 'commented', the target is an image model.

Comment: Thanks Pram, so I guess the first signal is the actual notification itself and the second handler is the one that generates the notification am I correct?

Comment: The only thing I'm unsure of is how to generate that action when a user comments. So I'm assuming it would be:def comment_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    #other routines here
    notify.send(instance, verb='commented')

post_save.connect(comment_handler, sender=Myphotomodel)

Comment: Yes. Ofcourse you can just use the actual notification only. I think the writer's suggestion here is for modularity reasons.

Comment: If the photo and the comments are separate models, the sender (in post_save.connect) should be the Comment model. However the target is still a Myphotomodel object.

Comment: Thanks Pram, really appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Django has a `signalling system` that allows you to easily attach functions (signal handlers) that will fired when a certain event happens. There are a number of default events such as when a model object is saved or deleted, but you can also create your own events making it easy to later attach code:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

> Django includes a “signal dispatcher” which helps allow decoupled applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the framework. In a nutshell, signals allow certain senders to notify a set of receivers that some action has taken place. They’re especially useful when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events.

The very important thing to note with these `signals` is that it's easy to think that these actions are fired asynchronously outside of the request/response loop, but this is not the case. They are simply a intuitive way of adding actions to events (i.e. when X is saved, do Y).